# VMware Workstation rights issue - Authorization Service will not run unless I open Workstation as Admin

Tags: windows-10, permissions, vmware-workstation

I get this error when trying to start any VM unless I open VMware Workstation as Admin:

- Host OS is Windows 10
- Workstation version 16 Pro - 16.2.4 build-20089737 - **up-to-date**

[image: Authorization Service will not run unless I open Workstation as Admin]

```
VMware Workstation cannot connect to the virtual machine. 
Make sure you have rights to run the program, access all directories the program 
uses, and access all directories for temporary files.

The VMware Authorization Service is not running.
```

Anyone know how to resolve this? I googled it but could not find anything.

Comment: Try reinstalling VMware Workstation. Uninstall, restart and install VMware Workstation again. The authorization service should now be running Try that.

Comment: Thanks, @John! I have no "VMware Authorization" service listed currently (strange how this can even work as Admin), hopefully that does the trick...

Comment: Please let us know if this is the answer - It was for me some versions back.

Comment: Run a "Repair" of the program & rebooting did the trick! Many thanks. Please write up your answer and I will accept it. :)

Comment: I do prepare an answer for you. Reinstall and Repair are very close for Workstation,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things you can try:

(1) Try reinstalling VMware Workstation. Uninstall, restart and install VMware Workstation again. The authorization service should now be running.

(2) Possibly Repair Workstation from Control Panel, Programs and Features.

Either approach should work as a Repair will reinstall Workstation so (1) and (2) are very close.

In either case, restart so the service starts. I have done this for prior workstation versions.